# Do Spring MVC Interceptors only intercept specific mappings?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Using Spring MVC, do interceptors only intercept defined controller mappings or can they also be used to intercept general requests made within the servlet context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring MVC interceptors intercept only request to controllers. For intercepting other requests use `Filter`s.

**UPDATE:** If you want to configure filters as Spring beans, you can use `DelegatingFilterProxy`, as follows:

```
@Component(name = "myFilter")
public class MyFilter implements Filter { ... }
```

(or `<bean id = "myFilter" class = "...MyFilter">...</bean>` in XML config).

Then, in `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <!-- By default, delegates to the bean of the same name -->
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you know of any good Spring-based Filter examples? I've seen only a couple of [not-too-well-documented] examples of using the `DelegatingFilterProxy`